# Ansible: how to run subsequent task for only newly created users?

Tags: ansible, user-management, password-policy

The user creation policy in our organization is to force changing password on first login and use SSH keys for remote connections; the password is only used to run `sudo` or login locally.

To force password change we commonly run `chage -d 0 <username>`. So, I need to run this in Ansible, but *only* if it just created user in the same play in previous task.

I create users with `ansible.builtin.user` module. My plan is to register it's output into the variable, then I want to run `shell` module but with some condition, and I need to determine the precise condition.

My playbook so far is:

```yaml
- hosts: hosts
  vars_files:
  - users-config.yaml
  tasks:
  - name: create users
    user:
      name: "{{ item.username }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
      comment: "{{ item.gecos }}"
      shell: /bin/bash
      groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
    register: users_processed
  - name: set password age to 0 to force change on next login for new users
    debug:
      var: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ users_processed.results }}"
```

So far, I found out the `user` module returns useful *changed* and *failed*, so my condition will definitely contain `item.changed and not item.failed`, but what other conditions I need to to properly catch only newly created users and not just updated pre-existing?

For reference, in the example output below `apushkin` was not changed, `nkhrushchov` was updated but *does not need* the password age to be reset, and only `rraskolnikov` was just created and needs their password age to be reset.

```json
ok: [host3] => (item={'comment': 'Alexander Pushkin', 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'group': 1000, 'name': 'apushkin', 'changed': False, 'state': 'present', 'groups': 'wheel', 'invocation': {'module_args': {'comment': 'Alexander Pushkin', 'ssh_key_bits': 0, 'update_password': 'always', 'non_unique': False, 'force': False, 'ssh_key_type': 'rsa', 'create_home': True, 'password_lock': None, 'ssh_key_passphrase': None, 'uid': None, 'home': None, 'append': False, 'skeleton': None, 'ssh_key_comment': 'ansible-generated on host3', 'group': None, 'system': False, 'state': 'present', 'role': None, 'hidden': None, 'local': None, 'authorization': None, 'profile': None, 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'expires': None, 'ssh_key_file': None, 'groups': ['wheel'], 'move_home': False, 'password': None, 'name': 'apushkin', 'seuser': None, 'remove': False, 'login_class': None, 'generate_ssh_key': None}}, 'home': '/home/apushkin', 'move_home': False, 'append': False, 'uid': 1000, 'failed': False, 'item': {'username': 'apushkin', 'gecos': 'Alexander Pushkin', 'state': 'present', 'groups': 'wheel'}, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {                                                                                                                                                                       
    "<class 'dict'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "append": false,
        "changed": false,
        "comment": "Alexander Pushkin",
        "failed": false,
        "group": 1000,
        "groups": "wheel",
        "home": "/home/apushkin",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "append": false,
                "authorization": null,
                "comment": "Alexander Pushkin",
                "create_home": true,
                "expires": null,
                "force": false,
                "generate_ssh_key": null,
                "group": null,
                "groups": [
                    "wheel"
                ],
                "hidden": null,
                "home": null,
                "local": null,
                "login_class": null,
                "move_home": false,
                "name": "apushkin",
                "non_unique": false,
                "password": null,
                "password_lock": null,
                "profile": null,
                "remove": false,
                "role": null,
                "seuser": null,
                "shell": "/bin/bash",
                "skeleton": null,
                "ssh_key_bits": 0,
                "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on host3",
                "ssh_key_file": null,
                "ssh_key_passphrase": null,
                "ssh_key_type": "rsa",
                "state": "present",
                "system": false,
                "uid": null,
                "update_password": "always"
            }
        },
        "item": {
            "gecos": "Alexander Pushkin",
            "groups": "wheel",
            "state": "present",
            "username": "apushkin"
        },
        "move_home": false,
        "name": "apushkin",
        "shell": "/bin/bash",
        "state": "present",
        "uid": 1000
    }
}
ok: [host3] => (item={'comment': '', 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'group': 1001, 'name': 'nhrushchov', 'changed': True, 'state': 'present', 'groups': 'wheel', 'invocation': {'module_args': {'comment': 'Nikita Khrushchov', 'ssh_key_bits': 0, 'update_password': 'always', 'non_unique': False, 'force': False, 'ssh_key_type': 'rsa', 'create_home': True, 'password_lock': None, 'ssh_key_passphrase': None, 'uid': None, 'home': None, 'append': False, 'skeleton': None, 'ssh_key_comment': 'ansible-generated on host3', 'group': None, 'system': False, 'state': 'present', 'role': None, 'hidden': None, 'local': None, 'authorization': None, 'profile': None, 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'expires': None, 'ssh_key_file': None, 'groups': ['wheel'], 'move_home': False, 'password': None, 'name': 'nhrushchov', 'seuser': None, 'remove': False, 'login_class': None, 'generate_ssh_key': None}}, 'home': '/home/nhrushchov', 'move_home': False, 'append': False, 'uid': 1001, 'failed': False, 'item': {'username': 'nhrushchov', 'gecos': 'Nikita Khrushchov', 'state': 'present', 'groups': 'wheel'}, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {                                                                                                                                                                                           
    "<class 'dict'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "append": false,
        "changed": true,
        "comment": "",
        "failed": false,
        "group": 1001,
        "groups": "wheel",
        "home": "/home/nhrushchov",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "append": false,
                "authorization": null,
                "comment": "Nikita Khrushchov",
                "create_home": true,
                "expires": null,
                "force": false,
                "generate_ssh_key": null,
                "group": null,
                "groups": [
                    "wheel"
                ],
                "hidden": null,
                "home": null,
                "local": null,
                "login_class": null,
                "move_home": false,
                "name": "nhrushchov",
                "non_unique": false,
                "password": null,
                "password_lock": null,
                "profile": null,
                "remove": false,
                "role": null,
                "seuser": null,
                "shell": "/bin/bash",
                "skeleton": null,
                "ssh_key_bits": 0,
                "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on host3",
                "ssh_key_file": null,
                "ssh_key_passphrase": null,
                "ssh_key_type": "rsa",
                "state": "present",
                "system": false,
                "uid": null,
                "update_password": "always"
            }
        },
        "item": {
            "gecos": "Nikita Khrushchov",
            "groups": "wheel",
            "state": "present",
            "username": "nhrushchov"
        },
        "move_home": false,
        "name": "nhrushchov",
        "shell": "/bin/bash",
        "state": "present",
        "uid": 1001
    }
}
ok: [host3] => (item={'invocation': {'module_args': {'comment': 'Rodion Raskolnikov', 'ssh_key_bits': 0, 'update_password': 'always', 'non_unique': False, 'force': False, 'ssh_key_type': 'rsa', 'create_home': True, 'password_lock': None, 'ssh_key_passphrase': None, 'uid': None, 'home': None, 'append': False, 'skeleton': None, 'ssh_key_comment': 'ansible-generated on host3', 'group': None, 'system': False, 'state': 'present', 'role': None, 'hidden': None, 'local': None, 'authorization': None, 'profile': None, 'shell': '/bin/bash', 'expires': None, 'ssh_key_file': None, 'groups': ['wheel'], 'move_home': False, 'password': None, 'name': 'rraskolnikov', 'seuser': None, 'remove': False, 'login_class': None, 'generate_ssh_key': None}}, 'changed': True, 'failed': False, 'item': {'username': 'rraskolnikov', 'gecos': 'Rodion Raskolnikov', 'state': 'present', 'groups': 'wheel'}, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item'}) => {          
    "<class 'dict'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "ansible_loop_var": "item",
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "append": false,
                "authorization": null,
                "comment": "Rodion Raskolnikov",
                "create_home": true,
                "expires": null,
                "force": false,
                "generate_ssh_key": null,
                "group": null,
                "groups": [
                    "wheel"
                ],
                "hidden": null,
                "home": null,
                "local": null,
                "login_class": null,
                "move_home": false,
                "name": "rraskolnikov",
                "non_unique": false,
                "password": null,
                "password_lock": null,
                "profile": null,
                "remove": false,
                "role": null,
                "seuser": null,
                "shell": "/bin/bash",
                "skeleton": null,
                "ssh_key_bits": 0,
                "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on host3",
                "ssh_key_file": null,
                "ssh_key_passphrase": null,
                "ssh_key_type": "rsa",
                "state": "present",
                "system": false,
                "uid": null,
                "update_password": "always"
            }
        },
        "item": {
            "gecos": "Rodion Raskolnikov",
            "groups": "wheel",
            "state": "present",
            "username": "rraskolnikov"
        }
    }
}
```

I am just struggling to deduce the proper reliable condition out of this output. The [module manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#return-values) says that `append` is defined when user *exists* and `force` is defined when state is absent and user *exists*. Does "exists" mean "existed before module run"? Is it safe to use the following condition:

```
    when: item.changed and not item.failed and item.append is not defined and item.force is not defined
```

or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-module-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) and create the list of present users

```yaml
    - name: Get all users
      getent:
        database: passwd
    - name: Set present users
      set_fact:
        present_users: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
```

After you update users get the list of new users

```yaml
    - name: Get all users
      getent:
        database: passwd
    - name: Set new users
      set_fact:
        new_users: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys()|
                       difference(present_users) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  vars:
    users:
      - username: alice
        state: present
        gecos: Alice
        groups: [guest]
      - username: bob
        state: present
        gecos: Bob
        groups: [guest]
  tasks:
    - name: Get all users
      getent:
        database: passwd
    - name: Set present users
      set_fact:
        present_users: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
    - name: Create users
      user:
        name: "{{ item.username }}"
        state: "{{ item.state }}"
        comment: "{{ item.gecos }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.username }}"
    - name: Get all users
      getent:
        database: passwd
    - name: Set new users
      set_fact:
        new_users: "{{ ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys()|
                       difference(present_users) }}"
    - debug:
        var: new_users
    - debug:
        msg: "Force change on next login for {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ new_users }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [test_11] *******************************************************************************

TASK [Get all users] *************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [Set present users] *********************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [Create users] **************************************************************************
changed: [test_11] => (item=alice)
changed: [test_11] => (item=bob)

TASK [Get all users] *************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [Set new users] *************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  new_users:
  - alice
  - bob

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => (item=alice) => 
  msg: Force change on next login for alice
ok: [test_11] => (item=bob) => 
  msg: Force change on next login for bob

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=7    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The playbook is idempotent.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this.